# How to debug multi-threaded code in GDB?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, gdb

I am trying to debug multi-threaded program with one thread that waits input from user. When I put a breakpoint at some function of other thread and run app, it switches into same breakpoint and then immediately at input thread, so app waits input from user and I can't do any command in gdb. I simply need see all stack before invoking same function. I can't make bt command in

Answer (score 1):

Does `thread apply all bt` answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can add commands to a breakpoint, see [the manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands). Something like this:

```
(gdb) break some_func
Breakpoint 2 at ...
(gdb) commands 2
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 2, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>thread apply all bt full
>end
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Breakpoint 2, ...
Thread 1 (Thread 0x....
...
```

#### Edit 0:

Oh, I'm guessing you get `gdb` printing this on you:

```
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

Just do the following before you do `run` (you can also stick this into `.gdbinit` file):

```
(gdb) set pagination off
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. However, I have following output: Breakpoint 1, 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---

and I can't input <return> or any key. Input hung up. Why? I'd like to continue debugging at that point. Is it possible?

Comment: Add `cont` to the list of commands before `end`, and it will continue automatically.

Comment: I can't type 'continue' when gdb is stopping on breakpoint. Input for some reason is freezing. But I'd like to continue debugging. I'm using gdb on Cygwin.

Comment: That's what I mean - add `cont` to the list of breakpoint commands. That way you'll get full stack traces of all thread at that breakpoint and continue execution automatically. You can also save `gdb` output into a file, see the manual.